# Calculate an orthogonal vector

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I have a matrix $M$ with $n$ columns, between $3n$ and $4n$ rows and it's rank is $n-1$. How can I calculate a vector that is orthogonal to all the rows of $M$?

I think that there are several ways to calculate the $n-1$ orthogonal vectors of $M$, but I don't know the "best" one, or what to do next.

I prefer an explanation/algorithm than a Mathematica command.

Comment: In principle it just boils down to solving a linear system of equations.

Comment: Use cross product?

Comment: Welcome to math.se! Please take a look at [how to format mathematics here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: @DHMO Cross products only work in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @amd in $\Bbb R^n$ you can compute a cross product of $n-1$ vectors.

Comment: @DHMO I’d forgotten about that. One has to pick out $n-1$ linearly independent rows to do this, though, and the usual way of doing that gives you the orthogonal complement as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think @mathematician-42 is right. Since the dot product of two orthogonal vectors is zero, then the system of equations is the dot product of the unknown vector with each row of $M$. Anything other than the trivial solution is what I'm looking for.